# Nodejs reading large txt files and converting encoding

Tags: node.js

I have a problem reading large `txt` files in `windows-1255` encoding.
This is my code that reads data from a very large `txt` file. How can i read very large files and convert the encoding from `windows-1255` to `UTF-8`

**Note:** using `fs.readFileSync` doesn't work well with large files because it doesn't return the entire file. I tried using it with the `encoding` package.

This is my current code that is reading the file:

```
 async extractDataFromTxtFile(file, values) {
        const data = [];

        let count = 0;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const s = fs.createReadStream(file.tempFilePath)
                .pipe(es.split())
                .pipe(es.mapSync(function (line) {
                        s.pause();

                        count++;

                        if (count > 1) {
                            //sort arrayData and create json of users
                            const valueItem = line.split("|");

                            const proceed = valueItem.reduce((acc, item, idx) => {
                                return {
                                    ...acc,
                                    [values[idx]]: item
                                }
                            }, {});

                            data.push(proceed);
                        }

                        s.resume();
                    })
                        .on('error', function (err) {
                            console.log('Error while reading file.', err);
                        })
                        .on('end', function () {
                            resolve(data);
                        })
                );
        });
    }
```

Comment: For large files, it is suggested to use either Streams (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) or read line by line (https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)

Comment: @Seblor, if you notice I am using streams to read it, my issue is transferring the encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So anyone else facing this issue I solved it by using `iconv` https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv stream option like this:

```
    const iconv = new Iconv('CP1255', 'utf-8');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const s = fs.createReadStream(file.tempFilePath)
            .pipe(es.pipe(iconv))
            .pipe(es.split())
```

All I had to do was pipe iconv to the stream

> Chunked data Say you are reading data in chunks from a HTTP stream.
>   The logical input is a single document (the full POST request data)
>   but the physical input will be spread over several buffers (the
>   request chunks).
>
> You must accumulate the small buffers into a single large buffer
>   before performing the conversion. If you don't, you will get
>   unexpected results with multi-byte and stateful character sets like
>   UTF-8 and ISO-2022-JP.
>
> The above only applies when you are calling Iconv#convert() yourself.
>   If you use the streaming interface, node-iconv takes care of stitching
>   partial character sequences together again.